# Hide iPhone simulator border (non-screen area)?

Tags: ios-simulator

The useless top and bottom border (black area) is too thick. Is there any way to make them thinner? I wish some kind of small buttons are displayed   for the home/power buttons, but this is too large.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no way to adjust the size of the bezels, but if you don't like it, just disable it in the Window menu:

```
Window -> Show Device Bezels
```

Comment: Thank you. I wish Apple had provided a more sensible option: small [home][power] buttons on the right side of the simulator screen. The bezels take too much space, but without it, pressing the home button is a pain in the lower back...

Comment: Please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com explaining your use case.  You can always use shift-cmd-h for the home button as well.

Comment: can i completely hide the device to use less memory?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, @the_prole.  If you want to use less memory, hiding the window won't help.  Shutting down the device will reclaim the device's memory...